# Using find with regex, exec, a glob, and a little concatenation

Tags: bash, find, concatenation, exec, glob

If I type

```
find . -type d -regex ".*src/main/groovy/.*" -exec echo groovyc -d classes {}/* \;
```

<sup>This finds matching paths below cwd and passes each to `echo` with `{}`</sup>
I get

```
groovyc -d classes ./mine/app/src/main/groovy/mine/*
```

<sup>This compiles groovy source files found in glob</sup>

which, if I copy and paste, runs flawlessly.

But if I take the `echo` out of that first line like this

```
find . -type d -regex ".*src/main/groovy/.*" -exec groovyc -d classes {}/* \;
```

I get

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: 
./mine/app/src/main/groovy/mine/*: ./mine/app/src/main/groovy/mine/* (No such file or directory)
```

What foul magic is this? Why does concatenating {} with /* only work when echo is involved? How to fix this?

Comment: What's confusing? It's echoing the `*` literally, not expanding it to the files that match it. The same thing happens when calling `groovyc`, it gets the literal name `*`, not the files that match the wildcard.

Comment: Wildcards are expanded by the shell, `-exec` doesn't run the command via the shell.

Comment: @Barmar ok fine. So what's the fix?

Answer (score 1):

As noted, [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) is something that a shell does for you. Programs don't automatically recognize `*` as a wildcard to match all files in a directory. If you want Filename Expansion to occur then you need to run your command in a shell.

Two examples:

```
# launch a shell for each directory found
find . -type d -regex ".*src/main/groovy/.*" \
-exec /bin/bash -c 'groovyc -d classes "$1"/*' _ {} \;

# launch one shell to handle all directories
find . -type d -regex ".*src/main/groovy/.*" \
-exec /bin/bash -c 'for dir ; do groovyc -d classes "$dir"/* ; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Seems to work. Not familiar with this dir method of populating a variable in a for loop.   Does this have a name? I've got some learning to do.

Comment: `for dir` is a shorthand for `for dir in "${@}"`, it loops over the positional arguments of the command. Documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: Curious. My tests seem to show groovyc only getting called once for both of these.

Comment: Your post only shows one path being discovered by find, so that sounds expected. If you think there's multiple paths that should be discovered then you need to post more info about what those are and where they are relative to where you're running the command from.

Comment: It's a sub filepath. It's showing up as a second file argument getting passed to groovyc. So you were not expecting to call groovyc once for each file?

Comment: What exactly is _ supposed to do here? If I replace it with 'bar' it doesn't seem to change anything. I still get `groovyc -d ./mine/app/src/main/groovy/mine/Demo.groovy ./mine/app/src/main/groovy/mine/HelloWorld.groovy`

Comment: The first argument to `/bin/bash -c` after the command string populates $0. It's unconventional to actually use $0 as a positional parameter so many examples will fill it in with unused data and start populating arguments at $1.

Comment: Ah, so $0 = _ and $dir = $1 = {} and $0 is simply not used. Why choose _ then? Is that a convention?